# jQuery Coda-Slider with scrollbar

Tags: slider, scroller, coda

I want to combine coda slider with a jquery scrollbar. Does anybody knows how to do that?

http://www.tradinx.com/codatest

```
$(function(){
   $(".scroll-bar").slider({
     slide: function( event, ui ) {
     // Code for triggering coda slider .. ??


    }
  });
});
```

--

```
<div id="slider">    
    <div class="scroll">
        <div class="scrollContainer">
                <div class="panel" id="image1"><img src="data/8f8bc5cb2fdac666c9534f7c4b78c010.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                <div class="panel" id="image2"><img src="data/42a4c582d65e46dda4ddcde70a5b2afc.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                <div class="panel" id="image3"><img src="data/30c32091eb1121f630c48016b04a6f04.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                <div class="panel" id="image4"><img src="data/31f3ae0aac735d2b9432e88108e75b86.jpg" alt="" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="scroll-bar"></div>

    <div class="photo-thumb-block">
        <div class="photo-thumb"><a href="#image1"><img src="small/8f8bc5cb2fdac666c9534f7c4b78c010.jpg" style="width:159px;height:119px;" alt="" /></a></div>
        <div class="photo-thumb"><a href="#image2"><img src="small/42a4c582d65e46dda4ddcde70a5b2afc.jpg" style="width:159px;height:119px;" alt="" /></a></div>
        <div class="photo-thumb"><a href="#image3"><img src="small/30c32091eb1121f630c48016b04a6f04.jpg" style="width:159px;height:119px;" alt="" /></a></div>
        <div class="photo-thumb last"><a href="#image4"><img src="small/31f3ae0aac735d2b9432e88108e75b86.jpg" style="width:159px;height:119px;" alt="" /></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to turn off the css div overflow of the mail images container (the long one) you'd see that there is already a scroll bar.

So my question to you is, what exactly is the scrollbar supposed to do?

Comment: Thanx for replying, well my customer wants that extra feature so that one can also scroll through the images.
Also he wants the 'panel' divs widths to be individual (width of image), no fixed width, that I will change.

Comment: ya... spend a few minutes flipping the overflow css on and off on some of the containing scroller divs... you'll see what i'm talking about.

Comment: thanx, yes i know, i installed the jquery scrollbar but don't know how to connect it with the coda slider ..

Comment: i dont think you have to use the jquery scrollbar. if you inspect the css with firebug, and turn off the overflow: hidden property on that wide div, it already will show a scrollbar.